# CSS file present but ignored first time after application is deployed

Tags: css, proxy, websphere, browser-cache, wicket-1.5

The problem we are facing is that after deploying a new version of our (web)application any user that opens the application for the first time (after redeployment) sees a messed up version of this page. If he presses F5 (so not Ctrl-F5) then the page is reloaded and everything is fine.

I investigated the behavior on a micro level by looking at one single span which color should be black but was white. I saw the browser was only considering CSS styles coming from *style.css* (in which the color is set to white). It should however also consider the styles in *history.css* (in which the color is set to black). In the inspector the *history.css* is present (I see it in the HTML head and in the CSS list of the inspector) but it seems to be simply ignored. Looking at the inspector after an F5 the history.css file is taken into account and the right color is set.

In case this is related to Wicket the application is running in deployment mode so it is using `MessageDigestResourceVersion` to name the CSS file. However, it does not feel like a 'simple' cache issue since *history.css* is present but ignored.

**UPDATE:**
It is not only the first time after a redeployment. Also, we never have it on our DEV or UAT environment but consistently on our STAGING environment. So, it does appear to be related to some server configuration (WAS 7, Apache, reverse proxy, F5 load balancer, mod_security, ...) but no idea where to look for now...

Comment: Is it possible that the stylesheets are not being processed in the order that they appear in `<head>`?

Comment: Not impossible but would be strange since it is a crossbrowser issue and only on one specific environment. I will look more closely at the head section next time someone faces the issue. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, when a session for a user is created, a certain parameter got reset (on IE9 only). The parameter (actually an HTTP header parameter: the SSO session id) is used by the F5 load balancer to identify the WAS server the user is working with. Since some resources were added with Ajax and the session ID was lost while loading the page the F5 was attempting to get resources from another WAS and that causes an access denied exception for those resources.